# Git Push Origin Master spits out error?

Tags: git

when I try to

```
git push origin master
```

my files onto git, I get a long list of errors that say:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "hooks/gl-pre-git", line 22, in

```
os.environ['GL_REPO'], sys.argv[1] == 'W')
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1076, in **call**

```
return self.__send(self.__name, args)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1403, in __request

verbose=self.__verbose

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1117, in request

return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1128, in single_request

http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1240, in send_request

self.send_content(connection, request_body)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1270, in send_content

connection.endheaders(request_body)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 963, in endheaders

self._send_output(message_body)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 808, in _send_output

self.send(msg)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 746, in send

self.connect()

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 724, in connect

self.timeout, self.source_address)

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/socket.py", line 404, in create_connection

raise err

File "/usr/lib/python3.2/socket.py", line 395, in create_connection

sock.connect(sa)

socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

gl-pre-git hook failed (256)

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Might anyone know why this is happening? I will try to remove my git repository and clone a new one I guess but I'll see how things go!

Comment: I think this is not C++ related, so I am removing the tag. I hope that is OK.

Comment: Note those messages aren't coming from `git` itself - they're from one or more hooks that you have installed in that repository. Not sure what those hooks are - are they something you've written, or part of a third-party package you're using, or something else...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL_REPO implies that gitolite is being used on the repo *server*. If you haven't set up gitolite on the repo server yourself, you need to contact whoever has set it up and notify them of the problem to get it fixed.

So there is nothing you can do on the git *client* end. It needs to be fixed on the server.

Comment: nice catch on the GL_REPO bit

Answer (score 0):

Check out your git hooks. (.git/hooks/gl-pre-git)  Looks like an error with a hook pre-git hook.

Comment: What if I can't even git clone into the repository? When I try to git clone into the repository I get the same error... Might you know a fix?

Comment: I would move all the files in .git/hooks out and try again.  Worst case, you move the files back.  pre-git runs before anything else, if it returns an error to the shell, git will not continue.